# Obtener todos los elementos de una lista que minimizan una función

Tags: algoritmos, scala

Digamos que tenemos una función de *"medida"* con la signatura:

```
def medida(x: A): Double
```

Y queremos obtener los elementos de un conjunto que hacen mínima la función de medida. Aplicando los métodos `min` ó `minBy` puedo obtener el primer elemento que hace mínima la función; pero me interesa obtener todos los elementos minimales.

Una forma de resolverlo sería volver a recorrer todos los elementos para filtrar los que tenga medida mínima, algo así:

```
val conjunto: Set[A] = ...
val minimo: Double = conjunto.map(medida).min
val resultado: Set[A] = conjunto.filter(medida(_) == minimo)
```

Pero se estaría calculando dos veces la función de medida para cada elemento, algo que quisiera evitar.

Podría hacer un *mapeo* para calcular la medida sólo una vez:

```
val conjunto: Set[A] = ...
val mapeo: Map[A, Double] = conjunto.map(x => x -> medida(x)).toMap
val minimo: Double = mapeo.values.min
val resultado: Set[A] = mapeo.keySet.filter(mapeo(_) == minimo)
```

Aparte de parece más complicado, recorrería dos veces todo el conjunto, que en mi caso se trata de un conjunto bastante grande.

Estaba pensando en resolver el problema de forma *dinámica* (usando variables de estado) o usando algún algoritmo de tipo *glotón* (*greedy*). Sin llegar a tanto, al final me he quedado con una solución que añadiré como respuesta.

La pregunta: ¿Habría alguna forma mejor de obtener todos los elementos minimales de un conjunto, que sea a la vez funcional y eficiente?

---

**Edición** 2016-11-29 (a partir de la respuesta de @willena

Aplicación la idea de usar `foldLeft`:

```
val resultado: Set[A] = conjunto.foldLeft((Set[Double](), Double.PositiveInfinity) {
  case ((conj, minimo), x) =>
    val m = medida(x)
    if (m < minimo) (Set(x), m)
    else if (m == minimo) (conj + x, minimo)
    else (conj, minimo)
}._1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recorrer tu conjunto de valores mientras acumulas los valores que te interesan mediante la función `foldLeft`. Con esta aproximación obtienes las siguientes ventajas:

- El conjunto se recorre una única vez.
- Los valores que no te interesan se descartan al momento.
- No se crea un conjunto de resultados tan grande como el original.

Sería algo así:

```
val miConjunto = List(3, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 9)

def funcionCostosa(n: Int) = n % 3

miConjunto.foldLeft((List[Int](), Int.MaxValue)) { case ((lista, mejorResultado), candidato) =>
  funcionCostosa(candidato) match {
    case res if res < mejorResultado =>
      (List(candidato), res)
    case res if res == mejorResultado =>
      (candidato :: lista, mejorResultado)
    case _ =>
      (lista, mejorResultado)
  }
}
```

El resultado del `foldLeft` es `(List(9, 3, 6, 6, 3, 9), 0)`.

Una posible mejora para el código anterior es parametrizar la función de comparación del resultado y el resultado inicial con el que comparar.

Comment: Sí, parece la mejor solución. Edito mi pregunta para reflejar tu respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que se me ocurre es agrupar los elementos del conjunto según el resultado de la medida:

```
val conjunto: Set[A] = ...
val medidas: Map[Double, Set[A]] = conjunto.groupBy(medida)
val resultado: Set[A] = medidas(medidas.keys.min)
```

No he hecho pruebas para comprobar su eficiencia.